# File.separator slashes Different direction

Tags: java, android, playframework, networkimageview

I have a Android app talking to a Play framework app,
the android app uploades an image to the Play app and also updates the path to the image. I'm using `File.separator` in both apps.

I'm developing the Play app on a Windows machine, but u it will be on a Linux box once completed.

My problem is File.separtor in the Play app is using `\`
but on the android app it's using `/`

So the path to image is stored as follows: `http://website.ie/assets/globalUploadFolder\user_name\profile.jpg`

I'm displaying the image in the android app using `NetworkImageView` and it's throwing a `Unexpected response code 400`due to this.

is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the code to upload the image is running on Android?

Comment: You are using an URL. URLs never have a backward slash. So `File.separator` is not appropriate here.

Comment: Yes I see my error, I should not have used `File.separator` at all, I confused it with an error I had yesterday relating to paths. thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Seelenvirtuose the issue was URLs never have a backward slash. So File.separator is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

Since URL's always use forward slashes, you can just use the `String` `replaceAll()` method. `yourUrl.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");`

Comment: Although a good solution I should not have used File.separator  at all in this situation. thank you for the alternative though.

Comment: shouldn't "\" be escaped?